# Understanding timezone strings in R

Tags: r, timezone

I am having trouble understanding how timezone strings are handled in R and why `Sys.time()` uses a different string than `Sys.timezone()`?

`Sys.time()` returns:

> [1] "2016-05-13 10:17:04 CEST"

`as.POSIXct(Sys.time())` works:

> [1] "2016-05-13 10:17:11 CEST"

And `as.POSIXct("2016-05-1 10:15:21 CEST")` works as well:

> [1] "2016-05-01 10:15:21 CEST"

However, `as.POSIXct("2016-05-1 10:15:21", tz = "CEST")` does **NOT** work:

> [1] "2016-05-01 10:15:21 GMT"
>   Warning messages:
>   1: In strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :   unknown timezone 'CEST'
>   2: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(x) : unknown timezone 'CEST'
>   3: In strptime(x, f, tz = tz) : unknown timezone 'CEST'
>   4: In as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(as.POSIXlt(x, tz, ...), tz, ...) :   unknown timezone 'CEST'
>   5: In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : unknown timezone
>   'CEST'

I know I can solve the issue with:

```
Sys.timezone(location = TRUE)
```

> [1] "Europe/Berlin"

And `as.POSIXct("2016-05-1 10:15:21", tz = Sys.timezone(location = TRUE))` returns:

> [1] "2016-05-01 10:15:21 CEST"

But I would like to understand why the above works like it does?
And suppose I have data from a different timezone (say New York), how can I know which string to use?

**Edit:**
The answer by Matt and Adams' link provided the answer to the second question: timezones can be looked on Wikipedia or by `lubridate::olson.time.zones`.

However, the primary question is still unanswered: why is "2016-05-01 10:15:21 CEST" a valid `POSIXct class`, while `as.POSIXct("2016-05-1 10:15:21", tz = "CEST")` is not possible.

Comment: I find this very helpful. https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/28038_1bcb9aa80ca84f27ace07d612872861a.html

Comment: I have good experience with lubridate. Perhaps you are looking for [tz](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/lubridate/docs/tz)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CE**S**T probably stands for Central European **Summer** Time. 
So during daylight saving time, CET becomes CEST, and in winter it does not:

```
as.POSIXct(c("2016-1-1 13:00", "2016-3-1 13:00",
             "2016-5-1 13:00", "2016-6-1 13:00",
             "2016-9-1 13:00","2016-11-1 13:00"), tz="CET")
```

returns:

```
 "2016-01-01 13:00:00 CET" "2016-03-01 13:00:00 CET"  "2016-05-01 13:00:00 CEST"  
 "2016-06-01 13:00:00 CEST" "2016-09-01 13:00:00 CEST" "2016-11-01 13:00:00 CET"
```

However, as @Matt_Johnson explained, CEST is not on official timezone,
so `as.POSIXct("2016-1-1 13:00, tz="CEST")` fails.

What does remain strange, that CEST is acceptable in a string, even if the time is **outside** daylight saving time:

```
as.POSIXct("2016-1-1 13:00 CEST")
[1] "2016-01-01 13:00:00 CET"
```

The help files from `as.POSIXct` and `strptime` don't offer any explaination here.

Answer (score 7):

The time zones specified must be those from the [IANA TZ Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).  You can find [a list of all supported time zones here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). `CEST` is not on the list.

In general, identifiers in the TZDB consists of the following forms:

- Location based zones, in the form `Area/Locality`, such as `America/Los_Angeles`, `Europe/Paris`, or `Pacific/Honolulu`.

  - This is the most prefered format, which you should be using whenever possible.
  - Some have more than two parts, such as `America/Indiana/Knox`
- Administrative zones with fixed offsets, such a `Etc/UTC`, `Etc/GMT-3` or `Etc/GMT+5`.

  - Other than UTC and GMT, these are primarily used for ships at sea.  They are almost never needed on land.
  - The offsets in these strings have their sign inverted, for legacy reasons.
- Older country-specific zones, such as `US/Central`, `Canada/Atlantic`, and `Egypt`.

  - These should be considered deprecated. They used to be zone entries a long time ago, but are now just "links" for backwards compatibility.
- A few of the more popular POSIX-style time zones, such as `EST5EDT`.

  - Also for backwards compatibility.  Don't use these.
  - See the section on posix time zones [in the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for details.
- A few common time zone abbreviations, such as `CET` and `EST`.

  - Again, don't use these.
  - See [this list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) and notice how there are many duplicate entries, making abbreviations somewhat ambiguous.  For example, `CST` might be Central Standard Time in North America, or it might belong to Cuba, China or Australia.
  - Even though `CEST` may not seem ambiguous at first, consider that many different IANA time zones use the same abbreviation, even though they may have differed at some point in their history.

Comment: Thanks (+1) for your elaborate answer on timezoness. But it still makes my wonder why is "2016-05-01 10:15:21 CEST" is a valid `POSIXct class` while `as.POSIXct("2016-05-1 10:15:21", tz = "CEST")` doesn't work.

Comment: Can't find a *precise* reference other than that `tz` must be a valid olson identifier, but what abbreviations are supported in the other form might be implementation specific, or perhaps ignored.  Or perhaps they're doing a rough match to a subset of abbreviations, or taking them from the output side and just taking the first that matches.  I don't see a hard spec on this particular point.

Comment: Try other abbreviations and see what happens.  What does it do with `BST` for example?  Do you get British Summer Time? or Bangladesh Standard Time?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I wish the world would only use a single standard in units of measure, be it time, length, temperature, etc. But until that day, this link from rstudio is one of the best write-up on dealing with time: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/28038_1bcb9aa80ca84f27ace07d612872861a.html

Specifically to your question

```
library(lubridate)
x <- as.POSIXct("2016-05-1 10:15:21", tz = "America/New_York")
with_tz(x, tz="Europe/Berlin")
[1] "2016-05-01 16:15:21 CEST"
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, it is indeed very usefull. It does answer my second question, how to find timezone strings: `olson_time_zones()` from lubridate package. However I still fail to understand why `as.POSIXct("2016-05-1 10:15:21 CEST")` works and `as.POSIXct("2016-05-1 10:15:21", tz = "CEST")` does NOT.