R merge timevis and scattered plot vertically to line up x axis (time line) perfectly
I would like to combine a timevis and a scattered plot vertically (timevis top and scattered plot bottom), so the x-axis and labels are aligned perfectly. I've tried few options, but subgroup labels on plot were distorted. Here is a working code that creates the two plots without aligning them. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
library(shiny)
library(timevis)

psa <- data.frame(
  date = as.POSIXct(c("2019-12-18", "2020-01-15", "2020-02-19", "2020-04-02", "2020-06-25", "2020-06-26", "2020-07-16", "2020-08-13", "2020-09-17", "2020-10-15")),
  psa = c(251.8, 65.5, 7.4, 9.4, 13.2, 13.20, 18.4, 15.3, 87.6, 90)
)

dataLog <- data.frame(
  content = c("Prostate Cancer", "Lymph nodes & Bone", "Bicalutamide", 
              "Leuprolide", "Abiraterone & Prednisone", "Zometa", "Enzalutamide", 
              "Prostate", "Docetaxel", "Blood", "Treatment"),
  start = as.POSIXct(c("2019-11-26", "2019-12-01", "2019-12-18", "2019-12-28", 
                       "2020-01-18", "2020-07-16", "2020-07-30", "2020-10-29", 
                       "2019-10-29", "2020-12-29", "2018-12-18")),
  end = as.POSIXct(c("2019-11-26", "2019-12-01", "2019-12-18", "2020-03-28", 
                     "2020-01-18", "2020-07-16", "2020-07-30", "2020-10-29", 
                     "2020-12-10", "2021-10-29", "2020-07-16")),
  group = c("Diagnosis", "Metastasis", "Hormone Therapy", "Leuprolide", 
            "Abiraterone & Prednisone", "Antiresorptive Med", "Hormone Therapy", 
            "Sample", "Chemotherapy", "Sample", "Treatment"),
  type = c("point", "point", "point", "range", "point", "point", 
           "point", "point", "range", "point", "range"),
  className = c("blue_style", "blue_style", "blue_style", "blue_style", 
                "blue_style", "blue_style", "blue_style", "mo_style", 
                "serg_style", "tso_style", "white_style")
)

# Define groups with nested structure
dataLogGroups <- data.frame(
  id = c("Diagnosis", "Metastasis", "Hormone Therapy", "Antiresorptive Med", "Sample", "Chemotherapy", "Treatment"),
  content = c("Diagnosis", "Metastasis", "Hormone Therapy", "Antiresorptive Med", "Sample", "Chemotherapy", "Treatment"),
  style = "font-weight: bold"
)

# Create groups and set nested structure
groups <- dataLogGroups
groups$nestedGroups <- I(list(
  NA, 
  NA,
  list("Leuprolide", "Enzalutamide", "Abiraterone & Prednisone", "bicalutamide"),  # Leuprolide as a subgroup of Hormone Therapy
  list("Zometa"),
  NA, 
  list("Docetaxel"),
  list("Hormone Therapy", "Chemotherapy", "Antiresorptive Med")  # Hormone Therapy as a subgroup of Treatment
))

# Add subgroup entries with specific styles
subgroup_entries <- list(
  data.frame(id = "Leuprolide", content = "Leuprolide", style = "font-weight: bold; border-width: 0px; text-align: right; background: #ffffff; font-style: italic;", nestedGroups = I(list(NA))),
  data.frame(id = "Enzalutamide", content = "Enzalutamide", style = "font-weight: bold;border-width: 0px; text-align: right; background: #ffffff; font-style: italic;", nestedGroups = I(list(NA))),
  data.frame(id = "Docetaxel", content = "Docetaxel", style = "font-weight: bold; border-width: 0px; text-align: right; background: #ffffff; font-style: italic;", nestedGroups = I(list(NA))),
  data.frame(id = "Zometa", content = "Zometa", style = "font-weight: bold; border-width: 0px; text-align: right; background: #ffffff; font-style: italic;", nestedGroups = I(list(NA))),
  data.frame(id = "bicalutamide", content = "  bicalutamide", style = "font-weight: bold; border-width: 0px; text-align: right; background: #ffffff; font-style: italic;", nestedGroups = I(list(NA))),
  data.frame(id = "Abiraterone & Prednisone", content = "Abiraterone & Prednisone", style = "font-weight: bold; border-width: 0px; text-align: right; background: #ffffff; font-style: italic;", nestedGroups = I(list(NA)))
)

# Combine all subgroup entries
for (entry in subgroup_entries) {
  groups <- rbind(groups, entry)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Testing styles",
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .vis-foreground .vis-group {border: none;}
      .vis-label.vis-nested-group {border-color: #000; text-align: left;}
      .vis-timeline { border: 2px solid black; font-size: 10pt; background: #ffffff;}
      .vis-item.vis-line {border-width: 3px;}
      .vis-item.vis-dot {border-width: 6px;border-radius: 6px;}
      .vis-background .vis-minor.vis-odd {background: #ffffff;}
      .vis-time-axis .vis-grid.vis-minor {border-width: 0px;border-color: #ffffff;}
      .vis-time-axis .vis-text {color: black;padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px;}
      .vis-time-axis .vis-grid.vis-major {border-width: 0px;border-color: #ffffff;}
      .mo_style  { border-color: #301934; font-size: 10pt; color: black;  }
      .ab_style { border-color: #FFAA33; font-size: 10pt; color: black;   }
      .serg_style { border-color: #B9D9EB; font-size: 10pt; color: black;   }
      .status_style { border-color: #008B8B; font-size: 10pt; color: black;   }
      .white_style { border-color: white; background:#ffffff; color: white;   }
      .blue_style { border-color: #17B169; font-size: 5px; Background: #17B169; color: #17B169; }
      .nestedGroup { border-color: black; background:#ffffff; }
    "))),
  timevisOutput("timelineCustom"),
  plotOutput("psaPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$timelineCustom <- renderTimevis({
    timevis(dataLog, groups = groups, options = list(orientation = 'top', editable = FALSE))
  })
  
  output$psaPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(psa$date, psa$psa, type = "p", col = "blue", pch = 19,
         xlab = "Date", ylab = "PSA Level", main = "PSA Levels Over Time",
         xaxt = "n")
    axis.POSIXct(1, at = psa$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
    grid()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Here is a path to your answer (but it needs some adjustments).
Changes in the source, explanations
Plot Widths

Plot1 Widths

widthLabel <- 400: Width of left plot1 labels. Also to block the width the label of plot1.
widthPlot <- 1200: Width of plot1.
used in:

tags$style(HTML(paste0(".vis-labelset {width: ",widthLabel,"px;}"))),
timevisOutput("timelineCustom",width=HTML(paste0(widthLabel+widthPlot,"px"))),
timevis(dataLog,...,width=HTML(paste0(widthLabel+widthPlot,"px")),




Plot2 Widths

widthLabel <- 400: Width of left plot1 labels.
widthPlot <- 1200: Width of plot1.
widthLabel-widthYLabelPlot2: Width of left div before plot2.
widthYLabelPlot2 <- 60: Width of left plot2 labels inside the plot2.
used in:

tags$style(HTML(paste0(".vis-labelset-pseudo {width: ",widthLabel-widthYLabelPlot2,"px;}"))),





UI
            timevisOutput("timelineCustom",width=HTML(paste0(widthLabel+widthPlot,"px"))),
            div(
              div(class='vis-labelset-pseudo',style='display: inline-block;'),
              div(
                plotOutput("psaPlot"),
                style=HTML(paste0("display: inline-block; width:",
                                  widthYLabelPlot2+widthPlot,"px;'"))
              )
            )  


Maybe some things coulbe replaced or optimized with settings in plot() : See the help of graphics::par() to set into base::plot()
Plot scales and datas

Plot1

to have the min and max of Plot1 and Plot2 timevis(dataLog,..., options=..

start=min(dataLog$start,psa$date)
end=max(dataLog$end,psa$date)





              timevis(dataLog, 
                      ...,
                      options = 
                        list(
                          ..., 
                          start=min(dataLog$start,psa$date),
                          end=max(dataLog$end,psa$date)
                        )
              )


Plot2

to have the min and max of Plot1 and Plot2  plot(psa$date, psa$psa,..., xlim=..

datas in plot(): xlim=c(min(dataLog$start,psa$date),max(dataLog$end,psa$date))
scales in axis.POSIXct: at = seq(min(dataLog$start,psa$date),max(dataLog$end,psa$date),by="month")





              plot(psa$date, ...,
                xlim=c(
                     ...
                     min(dataLog$start,psa$date),
                     max(dataLog$end,psa$date)
                     )
              )
              axis.POSIXct(1, 
                at = seq(min(dataLog$start,psa$date),max(dataLog$end,psa$date),by="month"),
             ...)

I've changed at parameter of axis.POSIXct() to seq(min(dataLog$start,psa$date),max(dataLog$end,psa$date),by="month"). You can change by "month" "hour", "week", integer etc ...
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.POSIXt.html
Server
            output$psaPlot <- renderPlot({
              plot(psa$date, psa$psa, type = "p", col = "blue", pch = 19,
                   xlab = "Date", ylab = "PSA Level", main = "PSA Levels Over Time",
                   xaxt = "n",
                   xlim=c(min(dataLog$start,psa$date),max(dataLog$end,psa$date))
              )
              axis.POSIXct(1, at = seq(min(dataLog$start,psa$date),max(dataLog$end,psa$date),by="month"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
              grid()
            } )

updated source
library(shiny)
library(timevis)

widthLabel <- 400
widthPlot <- 1200
widthYLabelPlot2 <- 60

psa <- data.frame(
  date = as.POSIXct(c("2019-12-18", "2020-01-15", "2020-02-19", "2020-04-02", "2020-06-25", "2020-06-26", "2020-07-16", "2020-08-13", "2020-09-17", "2020-10-15")),
  psa = c(251.8, 65.5, 7.4, 9.4, 13.2, 13.20, 18.4, 15.3, 87.6, 90)
)

dataLog <- data.frame(
  content = c("Prostate Cancer", "Lymph nodes & Bone", "Bicalutamide", 
              "Leuprolide", "Abiraterone & Prednisone", "Zometa", "Enzalutamide", 
              "Prostate", "Docetaxel", "Blood", "Treatment"),
  start = as.POSIXct(c("2019-11-26", "2019-12-01", "2019-12-18", "2019-12-28", 
                       "2020-01-18", "2020-07-16", "2020-07-30", "2020-10-29", 
                       "2019-10-29", "2020-12-29", "2018-12-18")),
  end = as.POSIXct(c("2019-11-26", "2019-12-01", "2019-12-18", "2020-03-28", 
                     "2020-01-18", "2020-07-16", "2020-07-30", "2020-10-29", 
                     "2020-12-10", "2021-10-29", "2020-07-16")),
  group = c("Diagnosis", "Metastasis", "Hormone Therapy", "Leuprolide", 
            "Abiraterone & Prednisone", "Antiresorptive Med", "Hormone Therapy", 
            "Sample", "Chemotherapy", "Sample", "Treatment"),
  type = c("point", "point", "point", "range", "point", "point", 
           "point", "point", "range", "point", "range"),
  className = c("blue_style", "blue_style", "blue_style", "blue_style", 
                "blue_style", "blue_style", "blue_style", "mo_style", 
                "serg_style", "tso_style", "white_style")
)

# Define groups with nested structure
dataLogGroups <- data.frame(
  id = c("Diagnosis", "Metastasis", "Hormone Therapy", "Antiresorptive Med", "Sample", "Chemotherapy", "Treatment"),
  content = c("Diagnosis", "Metastasis", "Hormone Therapy", "Antiresorptive Med", "Sample", "Chemotherapy", "Treatment"),
  style = "font-weight: bold"
)

# Create groups and set nested structure
groups <- dataLogGroups
groups$nestedGroups <- I(list(
  NA, 
  NA,
  list("Leuprolide", "Enzalutamide", "Abiraterone & Prednisone", "bicalutamide"),  # Leuprolide as a subgroup of Hormone Therapy
  list("Zometa"),
  NA, 
  list("Docetaxel"),
  list("Hormone Therapy", "Chemotherapy", "Antiresorptive Med")  # Hormone Therapy as a subgroup of Treatment
))

# Add subgroup entries with specific styles
subgroup_entries <- list(
  data.frame(id = "Leuprolide", content = "Leuprolide", style = "font-weight: bold; border-width: 0px; text-align: right; background: #ffffff; font-style: italic;", nestedGroups = I(list(NA))),
  data.frame(id = "Enzalutamide", content = "Enzalutamide", style = "font-weight: bold;border-width: 0px; text-align: right; background: #ffffff; font-style: italic;", nestedGroups = I(list(NA))),
  data.frame(id = "Docetaxel", content = "Docetaxel", style = "font-weight: bold; border-width: 0px; text-align: right; background: #ffffff; font-style: italic;", nestedGroups = I(list(NA))),
  data.frame(id = "Zometa", content = "Zometa", style = "font-weight: bold; border-width: 0px; text-align: right; background: #ffffff; font-style: italic;", nestedGroups = I(list(NA))),
  data.frame(id = "bicalutamide", content = "  bicalutamide", style = "font-weight: bold; border-width: 0px; text-align: right; background: #ffffff; font-style: italic;", nestedGroups = I(list(NA))),
  data.frame(id = "Abiraterone & Prednisone", content = "Abiraterone & Prednisone", style = "font-weight: bold; border-width: 0px; text-align: right; background: #ffffff; font-style: italic;", nestedGroups = I(list(NA)))
)

# Combine all subgroup entries
for (entry in subgroup_entries) {
  groups <- rbind(groups, entry)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Testing styles",
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(paste0(".vis-labelset {width: ",widthLabel,"px;}"))),
    tags$style(HTML(paste0(".vis-labelset-pseudo {width: ",widthLabel-widthYLabelPlot2,"px;}"))),
    tags$style(HTML("
      .vis-foreground .vis-group {border: none;}
      .vis-label.vis-nested-group {border-color: #000; text-align: left;}
      .vis-timeline { border: 2px solid black; font-size: 10pt; background: #ffffff;}
      .vis-item.vis-line {border-width: 3px;}
      .vis-item.vis-dot {border-width: 6px;border-radius: 6px;}
      .vis-background .vis-minor.vis-odd {background: #ffffff;}
      .vis-time-axis .vis-grid.vis-minor {border-width: 0px;border-color: #ffffff;}
      .vis-time-axis .vis-text {color: black;padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px;}
      .vis-time-axis .vis-grid.vis-major {border-width: 0px;border-color: #ffffff;}
      .mo_style  { border-color: #301934; font-size: 10pt; color: black;  }
      .ab_style { border-color: #FFAA33; font-size: 10pt; color: black;   }
      .serg_style { border-color: #B9D9EB; font-size: 10pt; color: black;   }
      .status_style { border-color: #008B8B; font-size: 10pt; color: black;   }
      .white_style { border-color: white; background:#ffffff; color: white;   }
      .blue_style { border-color: #17B169; font-size: 5px; Background: #17B169; color: #17B169; }
      .nestedGroup { border-color: black; background:#ffffff; }
    "))),
  timevisOutput("timelineCustom",width=HTML(paste0(widthLabel+widthPlot,"px"))),
  div(
    div(class='vis-labelset-pseudo',style='display: inline-block;'),
    div(
      plotOutput("psaPlot"),
      style=HTML(paste0("display: inline-block; width:",
                        widthYLabelPlot2+widthPlot,"px;'"))
    )
  )  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$timelineCustom <- renderTimevis({
    timevis(dataLog, 
            groups = groups,
            width=HTML(paste0(widthLabel+widthPlot,"px")),
            options = 
              list(
                orientation = 'top',
                editable = FALSE, 
                start=min(dataLog$start,psa$date),
                end=max(dataLog$end,psa$date)
              )
    )
    
  })
  
  output$psaPlot <- renderPlot({
    plot(psa$date, psa$psa, type = "p", col = "blue", pch = 19,
         xlab = "Date", ylab = "PSA Level", main = "PSA Levels Over Time",
         xaxt = "n",
         xlim=c(min(dataLog$start,psa$date),max(dataLog$end,psa$date))
    )
    axis.POSIXct(1, at = seq(min(dataLog$start,psa$date),max(dataLog$end,psa$date),by="month"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
    grid()
  } )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Thanks, is there a way to add monthly tick marks on timevis x-axis? The plots start at the same position but the intervals between units are not the exactly the same so the end points don't line up.

I've changed at parameter of axis.POSIXct() to seq(min(dataLog$start,psa$date),max(dataLog$end,psa$date),by="month"). You can change by "month" "hour", "week", integer etc ...
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.POSIXt.html

I've seen different timezone CEST and CET in particular in min() or max() because of 2 sources of datas. I don't kown if it has consequences for you. You can try to modify it if it bothers : https://stackoverflow.com/q/1395117/10489562 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/37205128/10489562
